# Linux command tidy is encoding urdu text

Tags: linux, tidy, htmltidy

I have to remove extra lines in an XML. For that I have come to know that tidy is the best option and it works fine for english language file but when I run it for an xml have urdu language text in it, it outputs encoded text like below

```
<field name="title">&#219;&#338;&#216;&#167;&#219;&#217;&#710;
    &#217;&#8224;&#219;&#8217; &#218;&#169;&#219;&#8217;
    &#217;&#8222;&#219;&#338;&#219;&#8217;
    &#216;&#174;&#217;&#219;&#338;&#219;
    &#216;&#183;&#217;&#710;&#216;&#177; &#217;&#190;&#216;&#177;
    &#216;&#167;&#219;&#338; </field>
```

I am amazed where is the problem.?

Comment: What encoding does the document declare? If it's ASCII (or defaulting to ASCII), it makes sense to encode non-ascii characters.

Comment: This document is encoded with utf-8 encoding